Hive MetaStore to Unity Catalog
I'm trying to migrate my Hive Metastore to a Unity Catalog.
I wish to keep the exact same storage architecture for schemas and tables.
In Hive Metastore, all Schema are created using a location on ADLS Gen2 (Azure). Then tables are automatically created into the folder of the schema with their table names.
For UC, I had to create an external location for the storage. Which is the same ADLS Gen2 storage than hive metastore. So when I create the catalog, I specify the path of the UC. But when creating a table inside it, I do not wish to have all this hashed named schemas and tables.
Is there a way in UC, when creating a catalog + table on external table, to get a simple path of the table.
Example: abfss://container_name@storage_name.dfs.core.windows.net/data/my_uc_schema/my_uc_table
What I get instead is:
abfss://container_name@storage_name.dfs.core.windows.net/data/uc_test/my_uc_schema/__unitystorage/schemas/ed6a256d-9ae0-4cd4-a859-e13018d3b88a


"I do not wish to have all this hashed named schemas and tables" - why?

When you create a managed table it will create folders with hashed names. Create an External Table in UC to control the folder locations.
CREATE TABLE ..
(

)
LOCATION 'abfss://c@s/';

@GaneshChandrasekaran Thanks! Do you know what could happen if I decide to keep hive metastore tables + UC tables with the same location? I guess both will have different meta storage, but the data will be the same? I don't want to force yet user to switch to UC, yet. I want both to be available for the moment

When the SYNC command is used on HMS - External (Delta), it uses the same Cloud location and creates a metadata copy in UC.
Both HMS and UC can access the data. From Governance it's not a good practice to allow from both sides, but technically it's possible.

"Managed tables" are managed by Databricks, so you don't control the actual location where the table/data is placed.
If you want to control the location you need to create an external table.
If you have an existing hive table with table-data located at abfss://container_name@storage_name.dfs.core.windows.net/data/my_uc_schema/my_uc_table then you can create a Unity Catalog external table that points to the existing table/data.
E.g. following code

creates a hive table at a specific S3 location (should be same for abfss)
then creates UC metadata to point to existing data

Assumes an external location covering s3a://bucket/delta, with appropriate permissions exists already. See this.
from datetime import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        ("data1", datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-01T00:00:00")),
        ("data2", datetime.fromisoformat("2022-02-01T00:00:00")),
    ],
    schema="data: string, ts: timestamp",
)

df.write \
  .option("path", "s3a://bucket/delta/kash/ext_tab2") \
  .saveAsTable("my_hive_schema.ext_tab2")



SELECT * FROM my_hive_schema.ext_tab2;
SELECT * FROM delta.`s3a://bucket/delta/kash/ext_tab2`;

CREATE TABLE catalog1.default.ext_tab2 LOCATION 's3a://bucket/delta/kash/ext_tab2';
SELECT * FROM catalog1.default.ext_tab2;

Databricks has been building more and more migration options, see if any of them do what you need.
